# Unable to use sessions in node.js

Tags: node.js, express-session

I developing login page.
If user successfully logs in , then I want to store user_Id into session variable,which I will be using to authenticate other pages.

**App.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/', index);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: "helloKey", 
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
    cookie: { maxAge: 180 * 60 * 1000 }
}));
```

**User router**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
User = require('../models/user');

//Login User
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var user = new User(req.body);
    User.login(user, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(500);
            throw err;
        }
        if (!user) {
            res.sendStatus(404);
            return;
        }
      req.session.name = user.id;
        res.json(user.id);

    });
});
```

Problem is if I execute this code I am getting **Cannot set property 'name' of undefined** 
What I am doing wrong?
Please Help.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that your routes are already setup before session so you have to reorder the code.
Move these lines

```
app.use('/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/', index);
```

Below the app.use(session) declaration.

```
app.use(session({
secret: "helloKey", 
resave: false, 
saveUninitialized: true,
store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
cookie: { maxAge: 180 * 60 * 1000 }
}))
```

Comment: Thanks ,that worked as expected . I have one more question, how I will know whether I am using **express-sessions** or  **connect-mongo** module for sessions .?

Comment: By looking at your code it looks that you are using express session. In app.use you used an instance of express session. If you use some other module then you would be using other module's middleware

Comment: I have also imported `var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);` , and also I am using `app.use(session({
 secret: "MySuperSecretKey", 
 resave: false, 
 saveUninitialized: true,
 store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
 cookie: { maxAge: 180 * 60 * 1000 }
}));`

Comment: Mongo store is just for storage. Express session will be managing all your sessions.

Comment: Okay, so is this the right approach , I mean even if I deploy my app with this configuration , will it work without any performance issues? Because I read , express-session should not be used for production web-app.

Comment: It depends upon the scalability. You can also use some other session manager if it&#39;s a big production app. Express session can be used if you don't have too much traffic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149930/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-arpit-solanki).